# Selecting id of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days and could not make any sense.
I use jquery to select the first element from the page and get it's id using:

```
$('#main li.twitter').eq(0);
```

The console log outputs:

> [li class=​"twitter event left" id=​"131325521001848832" style=​"display:​ list-item;​ ">​…​ li]

However:

```
var id = parseInt($('#main li.twitter').eq(0).attr('id'));
```

Outputs

```
131325521001848830
```

Not what I would expect! And if I try to select the element with that id it return an empty array so it doesn't even exist.What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: ID cant be a number. And why do you have to parse it as an it? Use as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric ids are valid in HTML5 and you can get away with it in previous versions.  However, the number is so large it cannot be accurately represented in the floating point representation JS uses.

Typing the number into the console

> 131325521001848832

outputs:

> 131325521001848830

So you are better off keeping it as a string.

Comment: +1 for *"Numeric IDs are valid in HTML5 and you can get away with it in previous versions"*, *and* for correctly explaining the limitations of JavaScript numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method constructs a jQuery object containing just the element at position `i` in the currently jQuery set. Therefore the console output you're seeing is the representation of the jQuery object (containing the DOM element).

An `id` is a string value, not an integer; so don't `parseInt` it if you want to retrieve it again at a later date.

```
var id = $('#main li.twitter').eq(0).attr('id');

// $('#' + id);
```

Furthermore, for future reference, you should always specify a radix when using `parseInt` (pass `10` as the second parameter to the function).